# NLP sentence analysis

Tags: python, nlp

I was solving problem 7 of chapter 8 from Natural Language Processing with Python.I know how to make grammar and draw tree. But I am stuck at sentence compression using NLP. 
The problem is given below:

**Analyze the A.A. Milne sentence about Piglet, by underlining all of the sentences it contains then replacing these with S (e.g. the first sentence becomes S when:lx` S). Draw a tree structure for this "compressed" sentence. What are the main syntactic constructions used for building such a long sentence?**

I am not able to understand what does it mean in below sentence.
"by underlining all of the sentences it contains then replacing these with S (e.g. the first sentence becomes S when: lx` S)."

The text which needs to be analyzed is as below :

**[You can imagine Piglet's joy when at last the ship came in sight of him.] In after-years he liked to think that he had been in Very Great Danger during the Terrible Flood, but the only danger he had really been in was the last half-hour of his imprisonment, when Owl, who had just flown up, sat on a branch of his tree to comfort him, and told him a very long story about an aunt who had once laid a seagull's egg by mistake, and the story went on and on, rather like this sentence, until Piglet who was listening out of his window without much hope, went to sleep quietly and naturally, slipping slowly out of the window towards the water until he was only hanging on by his toes, at which moment, luckily, a sudden loud squawk from Owl, which was really part of the story, being what his aunt said, woke the Piglet up and just gave him time to jerk himself back into safety and say, "How interesting, and did she?" when — well, you can imagine his joy when at last he saw the good ship, Brain of Pooh (Captain, C. Robin; 1st Mate, P. Bear) coming over the sea to rescue him...**

Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. However I think your problem is that the text of the books is a bit scrambled in the HTML version. If you look for a pdf version you will find that this exercise should read (e.g. the first sentence becomes   "S when S")